# How do I make the labels of my axis bold?

Tags: graph, stata, scatter-plot, axis-labels

I mean the 0 2 4 6 labels going up the side of the axis of a Stata scatter graph.

Is there any way to do this without creating a whole new variable as I've seen other people do?? This really shouldn't be so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone Stata and write Rosieata if you can think up simpler code!

More seriously, I don't know how a new variable would help here at all, but you give no code to discuss.

Here is some technique:

```
sysuse auto, clear 

set scheme s1color 

scatter rep78 price, ms(Oh) yla(1 2 3 4 5, ang(h))

scatter rep78 price, ms(Oh) yla(1 "{bf:1}" 2 "{bf:2}" 3 "{bf:3}" 4 "{bf:4}" 5 "{bf:5}", ang(h))

ssc inst mylabels 

mylabels 1/5, prefix("{bf:") suffix("}") local(yla)

scatter rep78 price, ms(Oh) yla(`yla', ang(h))
```